# Resized images not working – 404

Tags: images, 404-error

I'm having issues with images in Wordpress 4.6.1.
I have read numerous threads and there is no questions or solutions which are relevant to my issue (that I have found).

I have found the issue is related to the resizing mechanism. The full sized image loads fine, but the resized images, including the thumbnails in the media library fail with a 404 error. For example here is a link:

Media library thumbnail URL (not working):
http://sketchy.study/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/about-us-headshot-2-150x150.jpg

Full size image without the dimensions as part of URL:
http://sketchy.study/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/about-us-headshot-2.jpg

This is a new installation and I have all plugins disabled. I have verified the images are there (obvious as the normal size image loads). I also have another site on the same server, I have temporarily removed its .htaccess file and no difference was made. It also is not a caching issue as I have tested it with caching disabled. I'm also running php 5.6.x and gd is enabled.

My number one hunch is related to the resized image code. I'm assuming a folder is used to store the resized images (to avoid on the fly generation of the same image). I cannot find this so I think this may be my issue.

Does anyone know if a storage location is used for generated thumbnails/resized images?
If so, what is the name and location of this folder?

If it is not being created due to permissions or other issue, at least I know where to start looking. Of course, any other pointers or help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Both links are not working!

Comment: @Rishabh On all my browsers and phone, the first link loads the WP generated 404 page, and the second opens the image. Are you getting a connection to the site at all?

Comment: Okay, its just not image url But your whole site is not showing anything. I tried to enter just `http://sketchy.study/` and its showing message `Nothing Found`.

Comment: @Rishabh Yeah, that is the wordpress install saying that, I have no posts as of yet, but the "nothing found" message is an indication that the site is accessible. I have added a 'test post' so you can see that the site is working. There is also an image in it that doesn't work due to the resizing image my question mentions.

Comment: Site is working But your both image url is showing message `Oops! That page can’t be found.`

Comment: @Rishabh When I changed my IP, i had the same issue, even the full sized link did not show. I have found the full size images were not showing due to permissions. I have changed all the images to 655 instead of 644. Now the second link should display as intended (originally I had `about-us-headshot-1` & `about-us-headshot-3` set to 655, but not `about-us-headshot-2`.